# Beautifulsoup extract string partially

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautifulsoup 4 and found it really convenient! However, I got the problem when I need to split the string:

An example here:

I have a link which is

```
 <a href="http://nihao-wobuhao?%93%23%24%12&sort=102">NIHAO</a>
```

I get the line with `soap.findChildren('a')`, but what if I just need the part 'sort=102'?

I tried to use `soap.find_all(re.compile(^sort=.*?))`but it does not work, can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Extract the `href` attribute and then parse it using the `urlparse` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate a little bit to @Don's answer:

- locate the `a` element by, for example, text
- get the `href` attribute value using a dictionary-like access to `Tag`'s attributes
- use [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) to get the url query parameters

Working sample:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>>
>>> html = '<a href="http://nihao-wobuhao?%93%23%24%12&sort=102">NIHAO</a>'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(soup.find("a", text="NIHAO")['href']).query)['sort'][0]
u'102'
```

Note that in Python 3, you would need to change the urlparse import to:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`urlparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) will pick out the pieces of a URL. You could use that to get the query parameter you're looking for.